Is the GDL Airport Shuttle Still in Business?
Back in 2008, I used the GDL Airport shuttle. I was traveling by myself with only a small backpack, so I intended to use public transport to get to downtown. Once at Guadalajara Airport, I found that using public transport would not be as simple as I thought, as it would require a long walk to the nearest bus stop. It was raining, so I had to figure out another way to get to my hotel. Luckily, I stumbled upon the GDL Shuttle kiosk. If I remember correctly, I paid around 80 pesos for a ride to the Minerva area, which was almost a third of what a taxi ride would have cost me.
I have an upcoming trip to GDL, and I wanted to prebook my GDL Shuttle ride, but I have not been able to find if they are still in business. It seems like their website is down, and their social media has not been updated in a while. Does anyone know their current status, or if there is another shuttle company you could recommend?
